# How to trigger a delete via QMessageLoop on non-Qt objects?

Tags: qt, containers

I have some legacy code which has been running on an older Qt version where QList still had an autodelete feature on pointers (at least that's what the in-code comments said). So the GUI was passed pointers to data objects, stored them inside some Qt container and was responsible for deleting them appropriately when sth (user or internal signal) triggered a Qt event for deleting one of the data objects. With the auto deletion feature this seems to have worked smoothly but now that it's gone I'm running into memory problems under Qt5.

It seems like I somehow have to synchronize the deletion with the Qt message loop because it's every time triggered from within a slot. If I just hard delete it by myself, the program will crash at some point because pending Qt events try to access the deleted data when it's already gone.
I think deleteLater would already do the trick, however the objects in question are derived from QTableWidgetItem and thus don't own a deleteLater slot.

Comment: If you remove the item from the widget ``QTableWidget::takeItem(int row,int colum)`` and also remove the item from your ``QList`` noone should actually access the memory and you should be fine with a hard delete.

Comment: I seem to have found a solution. Problem was that someone called QApplication::processEvents directly after having queued an object with deleteLater. Generally you are correct though.